# Как добавить id к ImageButton программно?

Tags: java, android, imageview

Возможно ли добавить к ImageButton кастомный id в виде строки? Id'шки будут означать mac-адрес (16-ричное значение). И дальнейшая работа будет производиться именно с этими значениями. Создаваться ImageButton'ы будут динамически. Изначальное количество неизвестно и будет зависеть от ответа API.

Код для одной ImageButton:

```java
ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
lp.setMargins(15, 0, 15,15);
imageButton.setLayoutParams(lp);
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_settings);
```

Рассматривал вариант использования `setId()`, но там принимается как входной аргумент `int`-значение. Вариант с добавлением xml файла с id тоже рассматривал, но я не могу знать изначально значения. Есть варианты?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Все `View` имеют методы `setTag()` и `getTag()`. Эти методы позволяют привязать ко `View` (и любым его наследникам, к которым относится и `ImageButton`), а затем получить из `View` любой объект, в том числе и строку символов.